# How to avoid starving out lower-priorly work item sources

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have sources of items to complete with differing priorities, and the ability to to complete items is always saturated. How do you ensure the lower priority items are not starved out completely?

I am thinking I could combine the priority of a source with the time since it was last serviced to come up with a dynamic 'effective' priority. That way, lower priority sources would slowly be raised until they were high enough to be serviced.

I didn't want to reinvent the wheel here without at least asking, in case a more elegant solution to this problem exists. Thanks!

Comment: I’ve seen various ad-hoc solutions to this. I’m not sure if there’s a canonical one or not, but it’s a problem that e.g. the Linux scheduler needs to solve, so there probably is a lot of literature somewhere.

Comment: Yes for sure. I was hoping to avoid getting bogged down in implementation specifics (thread scheduling etc). It might be useful to take a look though.

Comment: Are you looking for the explanation or an actual implementation?

Comment: Just an explanation / other ideas than what I was planning to go with. Thanks

Comment: @displayName not sure why you deleted your answer. It's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: @D.C.: I just wanted to ensure that you are not looking for a code assisted answer and wrongly provide you with a theoretical.

Answer (score 3):

What you are thinking is a standard idea and is called [Aging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aging_(scheduling)).

> Aging is used to ensure that jobs with lower priority will eventually complete their execution. This technique can be used to reduce starvation of low priority tasks. There are many ways to implement aging, but all have the same principle that the priority of a process should increase as it waits in the ready queue. The increase in priority may or may not be equal to the waiting time of the process.

---

Your current thought is to assign priority to the process. Generally you would do that by putting all the process in a min (or max, depending upon your implementation) heap and then poll the heap...

Alternatively you can assign process to priority. You do that by keeping multiple queues/lists of each priority type (highest, high, med, low, lowest etc.).

- Keep multiple queues of each type;
- Get item from highest priority list and finish it OR assign a time quantum to each of the high priority processes in a round robin fashion;

  - If all processes in high priority list are served, start serving processes from lower priority until there is something added to the higher priority list again;
- As and when any process in lower priorities has been waiting for too long, remove it from that priority list and add it to the next higher priority level.

This too is a standard algorithm taught in Operating Systems.